# Add controls to GUI in background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a form with a top and bottom panel.
The user will be making selections in the top panel, and each time they change a value on one key field I destroy the controls in the bottom panel, then make a time-consuming call to another application (via COM) and add a list of new controls being added.  This refresh process takes several seconds.

I'd like to be able to disable the bottom panel while it's being refreshed, and allow the user to be able to keep working in the top panel.  Of course, this is all one GUI running on one thread.

Illustrated:

[image]

I played with BackgroundWorker, but of course it cannot directly create controls on the main thread's GUI.

Is it possible for me to do this, i.e. allow one part of the GUI to be disabled and rebuilt in the background, while the user continues to work in on another part?

Comment: In almost all instances creating the controls themselves isn't time consuming, it's creating the data that the controls are based on that's expensive.  You need to create that data in a background thread, and then create the controls from that data in the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy - thanks, makes sense, but the main reason for wanting to create the controls at the same time is that they are UserControls which have embedded functionality to retrieve the data from the secondary application (and build themselves).  See my comment to Reed's answer; is it practical to create them off-screen, then pass them back to the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to do this, i.e. allow one part of the GUI to be disabled and rebuilt in the background, while the user continues to work in on another part?

In general, no.  GUI elements/controls must all be created and used on the UI thread, and nowhere else.

The best way to create this type of scenario is typically to use a `BackgroundWorker` or other technique to get the required *data* on a background thread, then build your UI after the data has been loaded completely.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to composite the new GUI elements in the background worker, and then pass them back to the main GUI thread at the end?

Comment: @Geoff No - they need to actually be created and used on the main thread.  Creation is a key part, too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look at decoupling the control's data retrieval behaviour as you suggest, and then creating the controls upon completion.