# Download image files and create controls dynamically C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I am building a windows form application which allows users to download images file from url and set the images to picturebox while creating the Picturebox, two buttons and a textbox dynamically for each image.

Below is my code for downloading image file using loop in form_load method

```
noofimages = no of images

imagesnames = array containing images names

uploadnumber= folder name created with images

for (int i = 0; i < Globals.noofimages; i++)
{
    client = new WebClient();
    string url = "http://www.upload2printer.co.il/public/uploads/" + Globals.uploadnumber + "/" + Globals.imagesnames[i] + "";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    Globals.images[i] = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    create_controls(i);
}


Now create_controls(i) is a method responsible for creating the controls

private void create_controls(int index)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = Globals.images[index];
    pb.Size = new Size(200, 120);
    Button b1 = new Button();
    Button b2 = new Button();
    TextBox noofprints = new TextBox();
    b1.Size = new Size(20, 20);
    b1.Name = index.ToString();
    b1.Text = "+";
    b1.Location = new Point(x, y + 125);
    b1.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
    b2.Size = new Size(20, 20);
    b2.Text = "-";
    b2.Name = index.ToString();
    b2.Location = new Point(x + 180, y + 125);
    b2.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
    noofprints.Name = index.ToString();
    noofprints.Size = new Size(160, 18);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        noofprints.Text = "1";
    }
    else if (status == 1)
    {
        noofprints.Text = Globals.noofcopy[index].ToString();
    }
    noofprints.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    noofprints.Location = new Point(x + 20, y + 125);
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pb.Location = new Point(x, y);
    x += pb.Width + 10;
    maxheight = Math.Max(pb.Height, maxheight);
    if (x > this.panel1.Width - 100)
    {
        x = 20;
        y += maxheight + 30;
    }
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(b1);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(b2);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(noofprints);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

Now when i run the application and this form is opened the form is only displayed when all the photos have been loaded and all controls created.

What i want to do is download each photo and then create its respective controls while the form is displayed.

I also looked into multi-threading and async and wait but was not able to figure anything around.

I am a beginner and a self taught programmer so i know my code is not perfect so i would like your help in solving this matter.

Thanks in advance.

[below is the image of my interface i want to show pictures one by one not all at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNXwf.png)

Comment: Propably you are doing this in the Form_Load event. The Form will show up, after finishing this event!


Create a new Task in the Form_Load event and after each downloaded picture, add it to your Form.


Another hint:
You have to modify the location of your controls

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163966/add-controls-to-gui-in-background-worker. You want to keep the UI responsive and add controls on the go one at a time and render it as soon as you add it. I think this is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that can be very well solved by using the Task Parrallel Library (TPL) Dataflow approach.

But for the beginner, it might look complicated.

Read here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-using-dataflow-in-a-windows-forms-application

Generally what would you need to do is to create a separate `dataflow blocks` to handle specific piece of work.
In your case, you would have two blocks - first block could be responsible of acquiring the image from web, the second one might be dealing with updating the UI, by creating a controls for downloaded image and display it.